# Is Dual Factor possible during boot with whole disk encryption on Mac FileVault 2

Tags: disk-encryption, macos, multi-factor, one-time-password

Mac FileVault 2 is the default disk encryption for newer Macs that occurs in the EFI pre-boot phase.  The challenge here is that most smartcard drivers are loaded after the OS loads.

Is anyone aware of OTP or smart card technology exists and is compatible with File Vault 2?

I checked the Apple support forums, but found nothing.  My hope is that government or other secure institutions can offer advice regarding this.

Comment: What about a YubiKey? Since this acts as a USB keyboard, it should be possible for the EFI to interact with it on boot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible.

From: http://training.apple.com/pdf/WP_FileVault2.pdf

> **Two-Factor Authentication**
>
> *As discussed earlier, when using FileVault 2 (FDE), the initial authentication takes place as part of the EFI pre-boot authentication
>   process. At this very early stage of the boot phase, none of the
>   OS-reliant services are able to load because they’re dependent on the
>   OS running. This means that alternative authentication mechanisms
>   other than password-based  authentication aren’t supported at this
>   time.  Any support for additional two-factor authentication
>   mechanisms, such as smart cards or one-time passwords (OTP), requires
>   further development of those services in the highly restricted space
>   and execution of EFI. If an organization needs to use smart cards for
>   authenticating and unlocking access to encrypted storage, use of
>   container-based Legacy FileVault should be examined more closely.*